# Transpose a text file to csv using Python

Tags: python, csv, transpose

I'm totally new to Python. 
I have a text file that is really huge. I wanted to do two things to it. 
1. Extract a certain region from it, which I've been able to do.
2. Now transpose the extracted region and write to a csv file. This has turned out to be a little tricky. zip function didn't do what I want. Here's the data from print statement of step 1. I'd like to transpose this data.

```
Number  "A1"    "A2"    "A3"    "A4"

Data    "ABCD"  "ABCD"  "ABCD"  "ABCD"

Date    "Jan 04,2013"   "Jan 04,2013"   "Jan 04,2013"   "Jan 04,2013"
```

There's an empty line between each line. I need to transpose this data and save to a csv file (without splitting the date into two separate columns). I have many such files and the headers change for each. So pandas didn't work either.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
colnames= ['Number','Data','Date']
fw=open("output.csv", "w")
f= open('input.txt', "rb")
fi = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
l = f.read()
ll= [x.split(',') for x in l.split('||')]
cols1 = ll[0]
cols2 = ll[1]
cols3 = ll[2]

final_cols = [cols1, cols2, cols3]
s= zip(*final_cols)
df = pd.DataFrame(s)
df.to_csv(fw, index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Using zip, the output looks something like this- `[('N', 'u', 'm', 'b', 'e', 'r',`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That works fine for this particular file. But it may not work for the rest because the headers keep changing and here, I mentioned the headers.

Comment: just split into lists and then transpose with zip

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tried doing `text = data.split()
        for row in text:
            print(''.join(row))
            print >> out, row` but it has returned me an output like this - `A1 A2 A3 A4 ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD Jan 04 2013 Jan 04 2013 Jan 04 2013 Jan 04 2013` everything in the same column and by splitting date into three rows.

Comment: try my answer and see how you go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your data and re to remove the space in the date so splitting keeps the date together:

```
import re
with open("in.txt") as f:
    lines = [re.sub('\s(?=\d\d,)',",",x).split() for x in f if x.strip()]
    print(zip(*lines))
[('Number', 'Data', 'Date'), ('A1', 'ABCD', 'Jan,04,2013'), ('A2', 'ABCD', 'Jan,04,2013'), ('A3', 'ABCD', 'Jan,04,2013'), ('A4', 'ABCD', 'Jan,04,2013')]
```

Writing is trivial:

```
import re
import csv
with open("in.txt") as f:
    lines = [re.sub('\s(?=\d\d,)',",",x).split() for x in f if x.strip()]
    zipped = zip(*lines)
    with open("out.csv","w") as f1:
        wr = csv.writer(f1)
        wr.writerows(zipped)
```

Comment: This answer made me go back and look up `regex` syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can still use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("input.txt", delim_whitespace=True , header = None, index_col = 0)
data = data.dropna()
data = data.transpose()
data.to_csv("output.csv", index = False)
```

In the above code, data.dropna() allows to remove empty lines, and data.transpose() lets you transpose your dataframe.

The output looks like this:

```
Number,Data,Date
A1,ABCD,"Jan 04,2013"
A2,ABCD,"Jan 04,2013"
A3,ABCD,"Jan 04,2013"
A4,ABCD,"Jan 04,2013"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems, starting with your attempts to split the file with '||' and '"', when those aren't your separators. You can build a table line-by-line and then transpose + write into the csv file.

(edit) I Didn't account for spaces inside quotes. Updated to honor quotes and to use ';' as a delimiter since your dates include commas. I used a regex to find words without spaces or words in quotes, then removed the quotes.

```
import csv
import re

find_cells_re = re.compile(r'\w+|"[^"]*"')

with open('input.txt', "r") as f:
    # extract rows, filtering out empty lines
    table = [row for row in 
        (cell.strip('"') for cell in 
        (find_cells_re.findall(line) for line in f))
        if row]
with open("output.csv", "w") as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(rw)
    for row in zip(*table):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: this is still going to split the date which is the biggest issue

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - you're right. This turned out to be a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Set `delimiter=','` for changing to CSV.

Comment: Please elaborate and make your answer more detailed. As it is now, it does not provide real value.